# How to delay, then combine a function with another one after button press?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div class="header" id="headline">**Typewrter Generated Headline**</div>
<div class="theory" id="random">**should generate after headline, also as Typewriter**</div>
<button class="button" onclick="Type();Type2();displayImage()" id="generate">BRAINSTORM</button>
```

```
const list = [
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
];


const list2 = [
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
];
```

```
const getRandomNumber = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * max);

const getRandomName = () =>
  `${list[getRandomNumber(list.length)]} ${list2[getRandomNumber(list2.length)]}`;

const setRandomName = () => {
  document.getElementById("random").innerText = getRandomName();
    
};
```

the two lists are added and ramdomized and displayed in html

```
document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", setRandomName);
```

the function I am trying to nest / stack on top of the other function:

```
var i = 0;
var txt = '';
var speed = 40;

function typeWriter() {


  if (i === 0)
    document.getElementById("headline").innerHTML = '';

  if (i < txt.length) {

    document.getElementById("headline").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}


function Type() {

  txt = starter[Math.floor(Math.random() * starter.length)];

  i = 0;
  typeWriter();
}
```

Also, I tried to implement something like this to **sleep** but don't know how

```
$("#generateButton").click(function(event){
    setTimeout(function(){
        //Do what the button normally does
    }, 1000);          
});
```

It works on the single list but I can't get it working on this:

```
document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", setRandomName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
document.getElementById("generate").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  setTimeout(function(){
    //Do what the button normally does
  }, 1000);  
});
```

Comment: doesn't work, maybe I didn't put it in the right spot. I think the setRandomName / getrandomname output is missing in your answer?

Comment: Does it give an error in you're console?

Comment: I don't have any. I write it in the Tumblr HTML designer :(

Comment: Do you have more elements with the id generate?

Comment: No, only the button is using the id at the top

Comment: The code you posted actually worked – could you help me applying the typewriter-effect after the 1000ms?

Comment: Do you already have code that creates a typewriter-effect? if so you can just execute the function